# Homeschool during traveling

Tags: travel, homeschooling

I would like to travel with my kids for around a year starting from July next year. The kids will be 5 and 9 y.o. We will travel in Africa, Asia, north and south America... We will not stay long on one place.

The question is about home education of older kid. We are from Europe and according to our law it's allowed to have home eduction. But I don't know if it's possible to study during travelling and how difficult it is. Another thing is that a kid should pass exams after one year.

Maybe it will be better to skip one year of education and then catch up?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?  Are you trying to ascertain if it is possible to do home school while travelling?  If the effort is worth it?  If your kid and you will be able to meet the requirements with everything else going on?  If it is even legal to do what you are proposing?  If you are allowed to skip a year of schooling?  Also, the only question I see in the body of the post feels like it's bordering on being too opinion based and might get your question closed.

Comment: Have you and your kids previous experiences in homeschooling? Do you know which curriculum to tech for both of them in that year?

Comment: @Becuzz I'm not asking about law. I'm sure that homeschool is legal and I think it's possible to skip a year. I'm asking if the effort is worth it and if a kid will be able to meet the requirements.

Comment: @Marzipanherz kids has no previous experiences in homeschooling and I don't know which curriculum to teach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a full answer, but it doesn't fit into a comment.

I remember reading a book called "Moi, Jacob, 13 ans, globetrotter" telling about a family travelling the world, and I've watched a few Youtube videos of another french family traveling on a yacht.  Both seem to have no real problems with schooling their kids on the move.

It doesn't sound easy, either, though: I'm quoting from the book: "I was five and a half when my dad put my first school book into my hands. Since then, he sits in a corner every evening and spends three hours correcting the school work I did this morning and preparing my lessons for the next day."

Being a teacher myself, I think this isn't too much of an exageration. You'll have to spend a serious amount of time with correcting work and preparing lessons, unless your child's curriculum is standardized, in which case you can ditch most of the preparation work by getting the prepared worksheets etc from the school your child attends.

Obviously, you'll also have to provide time for "school" more or less every day, so you'll have to plan your travels with that in mind.

Comment: I taught every grade from K-10, and because I devised my own curriculum, I did put in that kind of time (but usually after the kids went to bed.) If the OP plans to use a 'canned curriculum' and has the teacher's manuals, it will not take nearly that amount of nighttime work.

Answer (score 6):

What a great opportunity for your family! Is it possible? Absolutely. Will it be easy or pleasant? Most likely, much of the time it will be an encumbrance. There are trade offs.

At 5, a hoomschooled child can learn everything they need to on the go. (I.e., the requirements are low. "Oooo, see those giraffes? How many are there? How many would there be if three more came to join them? What letter does 'giraffe' start with? Great! Can you print that letter for me?")

At 9, the demands are greater, and while you can read to your child on the go, do you want to? Will the child have a few (I'd say at least 3) hours a day of uninterrupted sit down and teach/learn time in addition to stuff you do on the go? Because if you want the 9 yo to go back to school into the same class as he was with before, he will need to master the same subject material to keep up. Homeschooled kids don't need to do homework at that age. But you'll need to find out the legalities (do you need to submit goals and objectives/lesson plans to the school district? Do you need to submit samples of his work? Or will a standardized test be adequate? Goals and objectives take time. Proff of mastery of the material may take time as well.)

Re: curriculum, in the US, schools are legally obligated to loan you *all* the materials they use for their regular attendees, but they do not need to provide you with the teacher's manuals (the answer book, the book that advises teaching approaches and related activities, etc.). So, you need to know everything that the child is learning (you learn with the child.)

Opinion: I would not pass up the opportunity to travel extensively for a year just for school, nor would I give the kids a year off. Homeschooling a 5 year old only takes patience. Homeschooling a 9 year old takes some time and effort, but even more, it takes a great deal of commitment. If you don't have it, your child will fall behind. That may or may not get you into legal trouble depending on your local laws.

I homeschooled my children with a curriculum mostly of my own devising. The year we built our house, the demands on my time between the builder and my job were such that I had to send them to school that year (but  some were older than yours.) I can't imagine that travelling the world won't be demanding and tiring as well. Only you can decide how committed you are, what your priorities are, and know the legal requirements of your country/state/province/etc.

And try to talk to others who have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Take a Nanny along with you on your trip (to handle the schooling duties). The Nanny can fit the schooling around your traveling and help to coordinate the classwork with the area you are in.
2. Make arrangements with your school district to send the children's work electronically each month. You can receive the months' lesson plans, then return the finished work for grading. If it's possible, it would eliminate a trunk full of papers to keep organized and transport from location to location. Of course, I'm assuming that you will have access to electriciy and the internet every week or so. Print out the worksheets you need for a week or two, then scan the finished work back in to send off for review.

I'm sure there's a way to make this work for you and your family.